# Enumerate Table of Contents in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have the following slide. 
a) I want it to have subsections numbered 10.1 and 10.2 etc. I had increased the secnumdepth(3) doesnt help. 
b) sub sections  are indented weirdly(horizontally side by side) . I want it vertically aligned/stacked..

Sorry if its duplicated. [image: Sub Section Numbering and Indention]

Codes for the section is

```
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}{\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add `\par` at the end of the redefinitions of the templates.
2. You can prepend `\inserttocsectionnumber.` to your current definition of the `subsection in toc` template.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]